# PHP - Organize an array of objects by attribute

Tags: php, arrays, oop, sorting

Below are the results of my array `$geocodedList`:

```
array (size = 6) 
   0 => 
     object (Geocoder \ Result \ Geocoded) [24] 
       protected 'latitude' => float -22.4363597 
       protected 'longitude' => float -46.8106841 
       public 'distance' => float 1500 
   1 => 
     object (Geocoder \ Result \ Geocoded) [14] 
       protected 'latitude' => float -22.4349613 
       protected 'longitude' => float -46.8275498 
       public 'distance' => float 1740 
   2 => 
     object (Geocoder \ Result \ Geocoded) [25] 
       public 'distance' => float 152
```

It is an array with several objects (Geocoded) inside. 
I want to organize this array by 'distance' attribute of these objects. 
I want the result to be:

```
0 => public 'distance' => 152 (item 2 of old array)
1 => public 'distance' => 1500 (item 0 of old array)
2 => public 'distance' => 1740 (item 1 of old array)
```

How to proceed? I tried several things but could not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.usort.php) to specify a custom comparison method:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a->distance == $b->distance) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->distance < $b->distance) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Or equivalent with anonymous function:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->distance == $b->distance) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->distance < $b->distance) ? -1 : 1;
});
```